# Java Disruptor pattern and low latency

Tags: java, performance, disruptor-pattern

Q1) Does anyone familiar with the Java Disruptor pattern know the size of messages they benchmarked their results against? I am writing a similar system (out of pure interest) and when I read the description of their testing there is no mention of the message size sent?

http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/wiki/PerformanceResults

Q2) Is the disruptor for computer to computer communications, or inter-process? I originally had the impression it was for computer to computer but their work is labelled "inter thread" messaging library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disruptor is not just within the same machine, it is withing a single process. When they say "inter-thread", they mean that it is for sending messages between threads of one process.

The message size is actually almost irrelevant because the messages don't get copied. The messages are all fixed at the beginning and reused, so it doesn't really matter how big they are.

Comment: I wouldn't say almost irrelevant. Ideally the ring buffer would be empty but in bust conditions, you'd want all the messages to fit inside the L2 cache or you'd get some undesired cache behaviour.

Comment: @TrevorBernard: Yes, you want the messages to be big enough that you don't get false sharing, yet small enough that the whole ring buffer fits into cache. If your whole ring buffer doesn't fit into cache, it probably doesn't matter what size the messages are.

Comment: @TrevorBernard: [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html) wrote "the ring buffers are large: 20 million slots for input buffer and 4 million slots for each output buffer." However that doesn't stop the current working set for each component from being efficiently cached.

Answer (score 1):

Although Im not entirely familiar, just exploring it...

1) It looks like from the perf test folder in the src that they are using the [ValueEvent](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/source/browse/trunk/code/src/perf/com/lmax/disruptor/support/ValueEvent.java) class, which just holds a long, there is also some other xxxEvent classes that are used in other perf tests that are slightly bigger but from what i can gather so far, only a long is used within the ring buffer.

2) I would assume it is for completely same machine inter thread comms. the latency & uncertainty of comms across machines would make it extremely slow. (relatively) and then the project would also need to deal with socket comms, which I haven't seen in this lib.

Answer (score 0):

1,Disruptor not care the size of message. but result should be linearly down by size of message(workload increased, the speed decreased)

In deed it's not care the message.

The **KEY** of the library is the **ID** of buffer. pointer, position, cursor, indicator, all both mean the same. 
Disruptor self call it as "**sequence**"

Once the ID got, the whole world only owned by you!:) so **ONLY one writer**. the real key point.:)

2,not C2C, nor P2P:). just T2T. the T is thread.  [peter-lawrey have a great library Java-Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle), can be used in P2P case. a new article on java dzone: http://java.dzone.com/articles/ultra-fast-reliable-messaging

3, the core pattern should be capable to clone to cross boundary use cases. every thing is ID. 
As to the message, customerized.

4, another important point, is the **cache of volatile**. [a great example on github](https://github.com/mjpt777/examples)

5, JDK8 intro a new annotation **@Contended**, seems sexy. [details about contended](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2012-November/007309.html)